# Is it possible to type dynamic properties on a registry class based upon input?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to port a registry object over to typescript. It's got dynamically named properties based upon a property of objects passed in. I might not design it this way now, but there's a substantial codebase using it as is and getting a good type def around it is a start to changing it.

How can I make this work? I get `[ts] Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'MyRegistry' has no index signature.` in the forEach blocks. And if it's not possible to type this, how can I change how I pass types into this registry object so that it is "typeable"? As long as the shape is the same in the end, we're ok.

```
class MyNode {
  readonly name: string
  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name
  }
}

class MyInterface {
  readonly name: string
  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name
  }
}

class MyRegistry {
  constructor({ nodes, interfaces }: { nodes: MyNode[], interfaces: MyInterface[]}) {
    nodes.forEach(node => {
      this[node.name] = node
    })
    interfaces.forEach(interfaces => {
      this[interfaces.name] = interfaces
    })

  }
}

const a = new MyNode('a')
const b = new MyNode('b')
const c = new MyNode('c')

const d = new MyInterface('d')
const e = new MyInterface('e')
const f = new MyInterface('f')

const registry = new MyRegistry({
  nodes: [a, b, c],
  interfaces: [d, e, f]
})

console.log(registry.a.name)
```

Comment: Would it be possible to make `nodes` and `interfaces` be objects themselves with the key-value pairs instead of arrays?

Comment: The reason I ask is because with this signature, it's impossible to tell at compile-time whether there are name collisions, which makes any index signature on `MyRegistry` ambiguous between `MyNode` and `MyInterface`.

Comment: Yes, but I don't get a different error. I tried adding a `[key: string]: any` which squelches the error but no implicit typing of the members occur, with an array or an object. (looping over Object.values at least)

Comment: I don't think you can define an index signature for a `class` that will allow specific property types to be inferred, but you could define a generic `[key: string]?: MyNode | MyInterface;` on the class.

Comment: Alternatively, `const registry = Object.assign({}, { d, e, f }, { a, b, c })` would infer all the properties correctly, but I assume `MyRegistry` has other functionality that you haven't provided in the example code.

Comment: it does have other methods yes

Answer (score 1):

The following example starts with the idea of just using `{a, b, c, d, e, f}` as the registry but keeps the other methods of the registry too:

```
type RegistryItems = { [n: string]: MyNode | MyInterface };

class MyRegistryBase {
  constructor(items: RegistryItems) {
    Object.assign(this, items);
  }

  otherMethod() { }
}

let MyRegistry: { new <T extends RegistryItems>(items: T): MyRegistryBase & T} = <any>MyRegistryBase;

const a = new MyNode('a')
const b = new MyNode('b')
const c = new MyNode('c')

const d = new MyInterface('d')
const e = new MyInterface('e')
const f = new MyInterface('f')

const registry = new MyRegistry({a, b, c, d, e, f})

console.log(registry.a.name)
registry.otherMethod()
```